# Checking database value script

Tags: performance, php

I made a PHP script to check value before update. This script is working fine. But, I wonder how to simplify this. If there are hundreds of columns to be checked then it's hundreds of PHP lines.

This is used for saving a log file for update. So, if data is updated then it stores a log in a table.

```
public function edit_project_master(){
$no_pro     = 'PRJ-2017-501'; //
$na_pro     = $this->input->post('na_pro'); //value for edit
$ja_pro     = $this->input->post('i_metode'); //value for edit      

$check_pro  = $this->MProject->get_det_pro($no_pro); //get data form table

//checking script
foreach($check_pro as $res_check_pro){

    if($na_pro != $res_check_pro['NAMA_PROJECT']){  //IF VALUE DIFFERENT
        $col_name;

        foreach($res_check_pro as $key_pro => $val_pro){
            if($res_check_pro['NAMA_PROJECT'] == $val_pro){
                $col_name = $key_pro;            //GET COLUMN NAME
            }
        }

        $data['ACTIVITY']       = "UPDATE";
        $data['OLD_VALUE']      = $res_check_pro['NAMA_PROJECT'];
        $data['NEW_VALUE']      = $na_pro;
        $data['COL_AFFECTED']   = $col_name;
        $data['TABLE_AFFECTED'] = "PM_REQUIREMENT_PROJECT";  //How to get table name automatically??
        $data['ANNOTATION']     = NULL;
        $data['EXECUTOR']       = $this->session->userdata('nip');
        $data['CHANGED_ON']     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $data['CHANGED_BY']     = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $data['STATUS']         = 1;

        $this->MProject->ins_system_log($data);             
    }

    if($ja_pro != $res_check_pro['JADWAL_PROJECT']){
        $col_name;

        foreach($res_check_pro as $key_pro => $val_pro){
            if($res_check_pro['JADWAL_PROJECT'] == $val_pro){
                $col_name = $key_pro;
            }
        }

        $data['ACTIVITY']       = "UPDATE";
        $data['OLD_VALUE']      = $res_check_pro['JADWAL_PROJECT'];
        $data['NEW_VALUE']      = $na_pro;
        $data['COL_AFFECTED']   = $col_name;
        $data['TABLE_AFFECTED'] = "PM_REQUIREMENT_PROJECT"; //How to get table name automatically??
        $data['ANNOTATION']     = NULL;
        $data['EXECUTOR']       = $this->session->userdata('nip');
        $data['CHANGED_ON']     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $data['CHANGED_BY']     = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $data['STATUS']         = 1;

        $this->MProject->ins_system_log($data);             
    }


}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid repeating whole blocks of code by isolating the dynamic components of your function and assign them to an array.  Then as you wish to modify the fields/columns to be checked, you merely need to update the array and not the functional/checking parts.

```
public function edit_project_master(){
    $no_pro     = 'PRJ-2017-501';
    $check_pro  = $this->MProject->get_det_pro($no_pro); //get data form table

    $checklist=[
        ['input'=>'na_pro','column'=>'NAMA_PROJECT','table'=>'PM_REQUIREMENT_PROJECT'],
        ['input'=>'i_metode','column'=>'JADWAL_PROJECT','table'=>'PM_REQUIREMENT_PROJECT']
    ];

    //checking script
    foreach($check_pro as $res_check_pro){
        foreach($checklist as $listrow){
            $pro = $this->input->post($listrow['input']); //value for edit
            if($pro != $res_check_pro[$listrow['column']]){  //IF VALUE DIFFERENT
                foreach($res_check_pro as $key_pro => $val_pro){
                    if($res_check_pro[$listrow['column']] == $val_pro){
                        $col_name = $key_pro;            //GET COLUMN NAME
                        break;  // I assume you want to break as soon as you find a match
                    }
                }
                $data['ACTIVITY']       = "UPDATE";
                $data['OLD_VALUE']      = $res_check_pro[$listrow['column']];
                $data['NEW_VALUE']      = $pro;
                $data['COL_AFFECTED']   = $col_name;
                $data['TABLE_AFFECTED'] = $listrow['table'];  // I'm not sure how you mean "automatically", this is "dynamically"
                $data['ANNOTATION']     = NULL;
                $data['EXECUTOR']       = $this->session->userdata('nip');
                $data['CHANGED_ON']     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $data['CHANGED_BY']     = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $data['STATUS']         = 1;
                $this->MProject->ins_system_log($data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also...

I added `break;` to the innermost `foreach()` assuming there will only be one match.  This is best practice because it avoids doing pointless iterations.

I made the value for `$data['TABLE_AFFECTED']` "dynamic" (modifiable via the `$checklist` array).  I don't know if this is what you had in mind by "automatic".